# Problema con clear: left;

Tags: html, css, web

Estoy haciendo una página web pero al generar un HTML desde una clase java, pero me genera el código de la descripción descolocado (me sale a la derecha del todo y debe salir debajo de la imagen), ¿a qué se debe?

Os dejo el link de la web: osmarentcars.esy.es, y éste es el formato del html:

```css
*{
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

#todo{
  width: 750px;
  height: 100px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-size: 14;
  margin: auto;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  background: transparent;
}

div{
  background-color: #00FFFF;
}

img{
  float: left;
  width: 96px;
  height: 60px;
}

.columna{
  float: left;
  width: 280px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.descripcion{
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>index.php</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 
    <link href="estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1><center>OSMARENTCARS - 2016 PROBANDO...</center></h1>
    <div id="todo">
      <div>
        <div>
          <img src='VEHICULO5.PNG.jpg' width='96px' height='60px'/>
        </div>
        <div class="columna">
          <b>I10</b><br/>
          <b>Precio: 12589.57</b>
        </div>
        <div class="columna" align="center">
          <u>FICHA TECNICA</u><br/> 
          Potencia: 87&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Consumo: 7.90l
        </div>
        <div class="descripcion">
          Descripcion: Aqui va la descripcion del coche
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Intenta ser más concreto en tus preguntas: "_me genera el código de la descripción descolocado_" no es una descripción clara del problema, ¿cómo está descolocado?¿cómo debería verse realmente? Además, sin compartes código, que sea el mismo que te genera el error, de lo contrario no podremos ver qué está fallando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estaba editando la pregunta para hacer el código ejecutable y que se viera el problema, y me he encontrado con que parece funcionar sin problemas. **Es el código de la página web externa el que falla porque es diferente al compartido** y no estás usando la clase que tiene el `clear:left`.

En particular, el problema que tienes es que la descripción en tu página no está en un `div` con clase "descripcion" y por eso falla:

```
<div id="todo">
  <div>
    <div><img src="IMAGENES\I10.png" width="96px" height="60px"></div>
    <div class="columna">
      <b>I10</b><br>
      <b>Precio: 12589.57</b>
    </div>
    <div class="columna" align="center">
      <u>FICHA TECNICA</u><br> Potencia: 87&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Consumo: 7.90l
    </div>
    Descripcion: Edición de HYUNDAI del año 2011 para circular en trayectos largos.
  </div>
</div>
```

Si en lugar de eso tuvieras algo como esto (que es lo que compartes en la pregunta), ya funcionaría:

```
<div id="todo">
  <div>
    <div><img src="IMAGENES\I10.png" width="96px" height="60px"></div>
    <div class="columna">
      <b>I10</b><br>
      <b>Precio: 12589.57</b>
    </div>
    <div class="columna" align="center">
      <u>FICHA TECNICA</u><br> Potencia: 87&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Consumo: 7.90l
    </div>
    <div class="descripcion">Descripcion: Edición de HYUNDAI del año 2011 para circular en trayectos largos.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Aparte de eso, parece que no estás cerrando bien los `div`. Tal y como lo tienes ahora, el `div` con id "todo" sólo contiene el primer elemento, quedando los demás fuera. Lo que que se vea todo mal:

```
<div id="todo">
   <div> AUTO </div>
</div>
<div> AUTO </div>
<div> AUTO </div>
```

Debería ser:

```
<div id="todo">
   <div> AUTO </div>
   <div> AUTO </div>
   <div> AUTO </div>
</div>
```

Comment: El problema es que la descripcion se ve a la derecha del todo y tiene que empezar debajo de la foto a la izquierda y ocupar todo el contenedor/longitud del css, por eso puse clear: left;

Comment: @omaza1990 como te explico en la respuesta, el problema se debe a que la descripción tiene que ir dentro de un `<div class="descripcion">DESCRIPCION AQUI</div>`. De lo contrario, no se aplicará nunca el `clear:left`. En el código que pones en la pregunta, sí que está ese `<div class="descripcion">`, pero en la página web enlazada no está y por eso se ve mal.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un poco de lío con las capas. Te dejaste alguna mal cerrada. Te pego aquí el body para los dos primeros vehículos, pon el resto igual:

```css
*{
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}


.todo{
    width: 750px;
    height: 100px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    font-size: 14;
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    background: transparent;
}


div{
    background-color: #00FFFF;
}


img{
    float: left;
    width: 96px;
    height: 60px;
}


.columna{
    width: 280px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}


.descripcion{
    clear: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
           <h1><center>COCHES DISPONIBLES PARA VENTA</center></h1>
<div class="todo">
 <div>
  <div><img src="index_files/I10.png" width="96px" height="60px"></div>
  <div class="columna">
   <b>I10</b><br>
   <b>Precio: 12589.57</b>
  </div>
  <div class="columna" align="center">
   <u>FICHA TECNICA</u><br>
   Potencia: 87&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Consumo: 7.90l
  </div>
  Descripcion: Edición de HYUNDAI del año 2011 para circular en trayectos largos.
 </div>
</div>
<div class="todo">
 <div>
  <div><img src="index_files/JAZZ.png" width="96px" height="60px"></div>
  <div class="columna">
   <b>JAZZ</b><br>
   <b>Precio: 56999.02</b>
  </div>
  <div class="columna" align="center">
   <u>FICHA TECNICA</u><br>
   Potencia: 93&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Consumo: 8.80l
  </div>
  Descripcion: Monovolumen pequeño con poco consumo de la marca HONDA. Perfecto para familias numerosas.
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Fíjate que he cambiado el estilo de id `todo` a estilo de clase `todo` (cambiar el CSS te #todo a .todo). Ya que lo usas más veces me parece más correcto así.

Comment: El problema es que la descripcion se ve a la derecha del todo y tiene que empezar debajo de la foto a la izquierda y ocupar todo el contenedor/longitud del css, por eso puse clear: left;

Comment: Si cerrase bien el div con id `#todo`, no haría falta poner la clase `.todo`. Bastaría con que el resto de divs quedasen dentro. ¿no?

Comment: @omaza1990 Para eso quita entonces el `float: left;` del estilo `.columna`

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro tienes razón, entendí entonces mal como tiene montada la página, pero a mi me sale lo que supongo que quiere.

Comment: No lo entendiste mal, tu idea es válida. Se puede hacer de las dos maneras :)

Answer (score 1):

Cambia en el css #todo por una clase .todo

```
<div class="todo"><div><img src="IMAGENES\JAZZ.png" width="96px" height="60px"></div>

<div class="columna">
<b>JAZZ</b><br>
<b>Precio: 56999.02</b>
</div>

<div class="columna" align="center">
<u>FICHA TECNICA</u><br> Potencia: 93&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Consumo: 8.80l</div>Descripcion: Monovolumen pequeño con poco consumo de la marca HONDA. Perfecto para familias numerosas.</div>
```

Comment: Solucionado. osmarentcars.esy.es